# Arabic/Hijri DatePicker for Angular 6

Tags: datepicker, angular6

I am searching for a Datepicker in Angular 6 which has the ability to show Arabic Date based on Hijri Calendar.

Can't seem to find one. Is there something available or we need to build it from scratch.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-hijri-gregorian-datepicker

Comment: @SooriyaDasanayake It is for angular 1.

Answer (score 2):

Ng bootstrap or bootstrap for angular has a date picker that supports Hijri dates and other dates formats. You can look into the link below.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/calendars